# Changes in test version applied in live version as well

Tags: 6, multi-sites

On a D6 multisite setup, under the sites folder, there are a bunch of sites. Two of which are the sites testsite.domainname.com and domainname.com.
They have the folder structure I put at the bottom of this post.

So the problem is that changes made in the test version also seem applied to the live version, obviously with very 
undesired results for the end users. 
I checked the settings.php file to see if the same database would be connected to but the 
data in both files are for different databases.

Changes applied to the test server that unintendedly have an effect on the live site 
are not only limited to changes in the domain_custom.module file. 
I noticed that changes made on the testsite in the page.tpl.php did the same thing;

**testsite.domain.com**
-modules
--domainname_custom
--nice_menus
-themes
--custom_theme
-settings.php

**domain.com**
-modules
--domainname_custom
--nice_menus
-themes
--custom_theme
-settings.php

Answer (score 0):

Of course i have to ask the obvious here, did you check out [multi-site install](http://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site)

Comment: Frankly I haven't. This is an issue for someone who has set up a mutli-site installation with a couple of other sites than those two folders mentioned in my post. But if we know that this issue doesn't occur in other sites in the same setup of which there is a test and live version, we can eliminate this from our checklist, right?

Comment: have you compared all configuration files? `.htacess` and `settings.php`? did you review the documentation i listed above?

Comment: I reviewed it, but like I said, the issue doens't occur on other sites of which there is a test version and a live version. I also already stated in my question that I compared the `settings.php` files. There is only one `.htaccess` which lies higher up the folder hierarch among the files that make up drupal core. Nothing to be found there.